# What does t states for in this equation?

Tags: neural-networks, mathematical-statistics, recurrent-neural-network

What does t state for in this equation ht=tanh(Whh*ht−1+Wxh*xt)? I found it in this article about recurrent neural networks: 
http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/
Another example is this photo [image]
There is t, t-1 and t+1

Comment: Do you mean stand for?

Comment: For example Wxh means weights from input to hidden layer. In that case what does h(small t) mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t` stands for time, as the input to a recurrent neural network can be seen as a time series.